# Access Subform Can't Edit Textbox

Tags: ms-access, textbox, subform, locked

I have a form named frmOrderDetails with a subform named sfrmOrderDetails.  I cannot edit any of the textboxes on the subform.
I have found many solutions on the internet but none of them work for me.
The frmOrderDetails has the following properties:

```
popup = Yes
modal = No 
Allow Edits = Yes
Record Locks = No Locks
```

The subform has the following properties:

```
Default View = Continuous Forms
Allow Edits = Yes
Record Locks = No Locks
```

The textboxes on the subform have the following properties:

```
Enabled = Yes
Locked = No
```

The textboxes contain data such as company names, products purchased, quantity ordered and quantity shipped. I execute a command button on the main form to update the subform (by changing the company name, for example). The update is done via a query (sqlCompany) ending with the following code:

```
Me.subOrderDetails.Form.RecordSource = sqlCompany
Me.subOrderDetails.Form.Requery
```

Then I add code such as:

```
Forms!sfrmOrderDetails.Form.AllowEdits = True
Forms!sfrmOrderDetails.Form.RecordLocks = False
```

or

```
Forms!sfrmOrderDetails.txtProductSize.Enabled = True
Forms!sfrmOrderDetails.txtProductSize.Locked = True
```

or

```
Me.subOrderDetails.Form.AllowEdits = True
```

Sometimes I need to change a quantity or the actual name of a product. None of the statements (or variations of them) work to allow editing the textboxes. There aren't any code errors, just can't edit any textboxes. All textboxes are bound. There must be a property to be set that I'm overlooking.  Can anyone suggest what else I could try?

Comment: Upon further research, I found that I cannot edit the textboxes because my query that fills the textboxes is too complicated.  I didn't realize that a query could be read-only.  My query is read only because the query consists of 5 joined tables.  Here is the **[ARTICLE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-data-in-a-query-6ca3edfc-6d66-4d90-8219-c2b258d5bed7)**  that explained it clearly to me.

Comment: You tried the Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates) as RecordsetType option? Show tables structure and the query. Work around with an unbound textbox and update via`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field = '" & Me!textbox & "' WHERE key = " & Me!key & ";", dbFailOnError`.

Comment: @BitAccesser Yes, the RecordsetType option is Dynaset.  I was looking at the unbound textbox solution but I haven't coded it yet.  I found that work around at the following **[LINK](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1118256-Can-you-populate-unbound-fields-in-a-continuous-form)**.

Comment: `Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates) ` is different to `Dynaset`. Read your office link

Comment: @BitAccesser Oops, I missed that point in the link.  I will try that when I'm back in the office tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: @BitAccesser Yes, Inconsistent Updates works.  Thank you.  Now to do more reading and understand the consequences of using this RecordsetType.